# Limit text after text counter is reached to 1000

Tags: javascript, jquery, copy-paste, nicedit

I am using nicEdit for a textarea in which I want to limit text entered upto 1000.There is a counter which will update when text entered and after 0 it would not allow user input.I am facing problem in one case of Copy Paste.

If there are 990 characters already entered and user presses ctrl+A,ctrl+c and ctrl+v.It does not restrict user (of course because counter was 990) but now text entered is 990*2.So only way left is I need to trim in case of counter value exhausted.
Doing that I can either use

**nicEditors.findEditor( 'summary' ).getContent();**   length or

jQuery('.nicEdit-main').text().length()

> to truncate input beyond 1000.But former solution wouldn't yield
>   result because nicEdit append a lot of divs in text areas and latter
>   solution would not be considering ENTER pressed by user.Please tell me
>   how to achieve this.

```
    $('.nicEdit-main').bind("propertychange input textInput ", function(e){
    var left=1000;
    if(jQuery('.nicEdit-main').text()!='')
    {

        var summarytemp = nicEditors.findEditor( 'summary' ).getContent();
        var countOfEnter = summarytemp.match(/(<br\ ?\/?>)+/g);
        if(null!=countOfEnter)
            countOfEnter = countOfEnter.length;
        left = max - jQuery('.nicEdit-main').text().length-countOfEnter;
        if (left < 0) {
            left = 0;
            e.preventDefault();
        }

    }
    $("input[name='countdown']").val(left);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In case your input/textarea's length becomes greater than allowed, cut it off at 1000 characters:

```
if (left < 0) {
   jQuery('.nicEdit-main').text(jQuery('.nicEdit-main').text().substr(0,1000))
   left = 0;
   e.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: As mentioned in comment I'll be loosing all formatting done by nicEdit and all /n values will also be gone using above solution.